# GridFactory getting generated into wrong location

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, model, factory

I have a custom module with backend management.

I have an observer on config save that uses the file upload to read submitted file to update the collection however this fails due to below;

```
class \My\MODULE\Model\Grid does not exist
```

Caused by, for some reason, when compile/content-deply is run and the generation is creating the GridFactory in;

```
generated\code\My\MODULE\Model\GridFactory.php
// ** should be in generated\code\My\Module\Model\GridFactory.php **
```

This is the issue, not sure why this is both capitalizing the Module name & then of course, generating this into incorrect location hence breaking any functionality (although admin forms are working for this module on save) and I can see other generation items are created in the correct location.

I have other modules copied & refactored/renamed but **are not** having the same issue at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my own mistake...

As I am integrating My/Module ***GridFactory*** into another module via dependency injection, it was here that I was adding the injection where the incorrect naming was written/injected as per below;

```
//adding dep. injection to My\OtherModule\Helper\Data.php
//see below mistake of capitalization in naming injection

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \My\MODULE\Model\GridFactory $gridFactory

)
```

Updating to the correct naming and running CLI commands to update/clean/generate fixed the issues on the backend.